# can't copy data from database to another? MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Please I can't copy data from database A to B
I have same tables in A & B and same columns too.

I want to copy Data from A.profile to B.profile

This is my code : ( same pass,user, localhost)

```
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)or die("cannot connect");
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass,true)or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("A")or die("cannot select DB");
mysql_select_db("B")or die("cannot select DB");

$SQL = "INSERT INTO B.compte SELECT * FROM A.compte";
$result=mysql_query($SQL);
```

please helps me !!!

Comment: 1) mysql_* functions are deprecated and shouldn't be used if at all possible. 2) You should be setting each of those connections (mysql_connect) to a variable so you can define which connection to use. 3) Frankly, I'm not convinced that query will actually work across multiple databases, your best bet (unless told otherwise) is to export the data and import in 2 parts.

Comment: the first problem is using mysql_* functions

Comment: really i didn't understand mr,@JonStirling , can u make a code for me.

Comment: @MoulayOmar I won't write the code for you, but here's a breakdown. First, connect to DB A and SELECT all the data you want to put in the other database into an array variable. Next, connect to database B, loop round the data from the first part and insert into the table on database B (either row by row, or by generating a bulk insert SQL query). What the best option is actually depends on what you're trying to achieve and why.

Comment: i know  the mysql command to copy data from A.profile to  B.profile
i only need how to do correct connexion and query_ mysql!!
i mean the problem using function my sql !!

Answer (score 1):

Hope i got your question right, you wrote that those two database schemas are on the same machine (localhost). 
If so, one of the easiest ways would be:

- grant SELECT right for user A to see user B's schema
- then just simply insert from table B's table, reading from A's table

For granting in database B:

`GRANT SELECT ON A TO 'B'@'localhost';`

Then the insert/select command could be like:

`INSERT INTO B.compte VALUES (SELECT * FROM A.compte);`